# How does `rpart` in R decide on splits

Tags: r, regression, cart

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)  
library(rattle)
tree <- rpart(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data = iris))
fancyRpartPlot((tree))
```

[image]

From my understanding, `rpart` fits a regression model at each partition of the tree. Since my outcome is continuous, the number at the top of each box is the averaged value of my response variable (i.e. = 5.8 at the root). My question is, how does `rpart` decide on which predictor to split on and at what value of that predictor? That is, how did the function decide that the first split should be on Petal.Width, and how did it decide on Petal.Width < 1.1?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says that it follows the procedure from Breiman L., Friedman J. H., Olshen R. A., and Stone, C. J. (1984) *Classification and Regression Trees*. Wadsworth.

I don't have access to this book, but someone who does could expand this answer (it's a Community Wiki) to explain the exact procedure.

Answer (score 3):

If the response is numeric (as opposed to qualitative) rpart chooses the split on the variable and threshold that produces the largest decrease in "impurity", defined as the difference of variance in the parent node and the (weighted) variances in the children nodes.